# Question about $q$-expansion principle for modular forms

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-forms

I am reading Zagier's lectures "The 1-2-3 of Modular Forms".

Before formulate the question let me introduce some notations.

Let $z$ be the coordinate on the upper-half plane $\mathbb{H}$ and $q=\text{exp}(2\pi iz)$. Theta function $\theta(z)$ is defined as follows

$$\theta(z)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}=1+2q+2q^4+2q^9+2q^{16}+...\,.$$
On page 27 Zagier defined two variants of this function:

$$\theta_M(z)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^nq^{n^2}=1-2q+2q^4-2q^9...\,,$$

$$\theta_F(z)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}+1/2}q^{n^2}=2q^{1/4}+2q^{9/4}+2q^{25/4}+...\,.$$

Then he states that there is an identity

$$\theta(z)^4=\theta_M(z)^4+\theta_F(z)^4.$$

To see this he makes the following claim:

> by the $q$-expansion principle all we have to do to prove it
>   is to verify the equality of a finite number of coefficients (here just one).

Can anobody explain me what does he mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is not at all clear to me that "the $q$-expansion principle" genuinely refers to the causal mechanism that he wants to invoke. Maybe it means different things to different people... In any case, the point is that a space of holomorphic modular forms of a given level is finite-dimensional... and, in fact, there are various not-so-hard estimates of how many coefficients one must check before being sure of equality. If one knows (for some other reason) that the dimension is $1$, for example, checking a single coefficient suffices.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some precise formulations of results about the estimates?

Comment: This is late, but I think you're looking for the "Sturm bound": https://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/cmf.sturm_bound